# Android Kotlin Geocoder DEADLINE_EXCEEDED on Android when getting location coordinates/adresses

Tags: android, geocoder, android-tiramisu

In my android app i am trying to get the address from `lat` `lng` using the [Geocoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/location/Geocoder) using [`getFromLocation`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/location/Geocoder#getfromlocation_1) method and the [`GeocodeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/location/Geocoder.GeocodeListener)
but sometimes the app is getting crashed

##### Crash Log

```
Caused by java.io.IOException: egma: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED: Deadline CallOptions will be exceeded in 4.959774531s. 
       at android.location.Geocoder$GeocodeListener.getResults(Geocoder.java:246)
       at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:134)
```

### Code

```
geocoder.getFromLocation(
  latLng.latitude,
  latLng.longitude,
  1,
  object : Geocoder.GeocodeListener {
            override fun onGeocode(addresses: MutableList<Address>) {
              val addressLine = addresses.first().getAddressLine(0)
                   onAddressResult(addressLine, null) // callback
             }

             override fun onError(errorMessage: String?) {
               super.onError(errorMessage)
                  onAddressResult(null, errorMessage)
             }
  },
)
```

What is the reason for the crash. how can i avoid it?

Comment: How did you solve this problem? I am getting the same issue, in my live production application. And I am not able to find the exact solution to this problem. Can you please help?

Comment: @RoopKishore used web version 
 https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/requests-geocoding#GeocodingResponses .. refer link.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, you can use coroutines to perform network operations asynchronously so that the main thread doesn't block, I solved it like this

```
      addressesname = addressesname(lat, lng, geocoder)

      private suspend fun addressesname(lat: Double, lng: Double,geocoder: Geocoder) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
         var addressesname = ""
         try {
              // For Android SDK < 33, the addresses list will be still obtained from the getFromLocation() method
              val addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1) as MutableList<Address>
              addressesname = addresses[0].getAddressLine(0)

         }catch (e :Exception){
              showErrorSnackBar("Tienes latencia, revisa tus datos moviles")
         }
         addressesname
      }
```

Comment: I think, this crash is not related to threading. It's internal crash within geocoding library possibly related to it's request scheduling mechanism.